# how to write text in tikz node with tikzstyle?

Tags: latex, tikz

i have this code:

```
\colorlet{one}{red}
\tikzstyle{fillone}=[fill=one,insert path={circle[radius=\rad]}]
```

how can i add a text in this '\tikzstyle'? i found some options like 'text=color', 'text centered'...

```
\tikzstyle{fillone}=[fill=one,insert path={circle[radius=\rad]}, text=white, font=\itshape, text width = 1pt]
```

can i write something like 'text="1"' to write '1' in every red node?

Comment: Don't use tikzstyle, this is deprecated. Have a look at the tikz user guide for `\tikzset` instead. That being said, please make a compilable [mre] so we can see how you use your node.

Comment: There's another question with answers about [modifying (not setting or overriding) the contents of a node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286314/)